# Python XPath scraping says list has no text attribute

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I am using a code to scrape a PDF to generate a relevant dictionary. My code works when I access each text block individually, i.e

```
x = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(u.read())
    r = lxml.etree.fromstring(x)
    s = r.xpath('//page[@number="142"]/text[@left = "134"]')
    print s[8].text
```

print s[0],s[1].. all seem to work but when I try the same for

```
x = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(u.read())
    r = lxml.etree.fromstring(x)
    s = r.xpath('//page[@number="142"]/text[@left = "134"]')
    print s[0:8].text
```

I get this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: you could just add `/text()` to the end of your xpath expression if all you care about is the text from each node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` is an attribute of each element, not of the list.

Iterate each elements.

```
x = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(u.read())
r = lxml.etree.fromstring(x)
s = r.xpath('//page[@number="142"]/text[@left = "134"]')
for elem in s[:8]:
    print elem.text
```

or use list comprehension:

```
x = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(u.read())
r = lxml.etree.fromstring(x)
s = r.xpath('//page[@number="142"]/text[@left = "134"]')
print [elem.text for elem in s[:8]]
```